# Too much RAM usage, but processes are less

Tags: 16.04

I don't know why Firefox is still running. I tried to kill it using `killall` and even tried to end the process using system monitor. I have 4GB of RAM, and 90% of it is always used.

[image: Processes Showing it's Memory Size]

Comment: Also see [Linux at my RAM!](http://www.linuxatemyram.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, `killall` sends the `TERM` signal, which tells the program to exit, but which the program can handle any way it wants to, including ignoring it.

Try `killall -9 firefox`, which will send the `KILL` signal instead, which kills the program regardless.

Comment: But my question is, why is it still occupying my ram when I closed the program...

Comment: Can you prove it still consumes RAM? E.g. by comparing the output of `free -h` before starting Firefox, while it's running and after closing it?

Comment: If I had to guess, it was still there because Firefox froze while closing.

Comment: @Olathe how to avoid it.... I have very less knowledge about operating systems though I studied in my bachelors... i am thinking of expanding my RAM to 8GB(now 4GB)... my doubt is, will the processes occupy same size after expanding, or they will occupy more as there is more RAM... I mean size of process proportional to RAM ???